# How Can I get all musicbrainz ids associated with an artist?

Tags: xml, api, http, musicbrainz

Given a music brainz artist id (eg - Bob Dylan = 72c536dc-7137-4477-a521-567eeb840fa8 ), I can query music brainz xml web service for his/her tracks:

http://musicbrainz.org/ws/2/artist/72c536dc-7137-4477-a521-567eeb840fa8?inc=recordings

The total "count" returned is 14036. Their site says that you can use "offset" for paging:
https://musicbrainz.org/doc/Development/XML_Web_Service/Version_2#Paging

Though: 
http://musicbrainz.org/ws/2/artist/72c536dc-7137-4477-a521-567eeb840fa8?inc=recordings&offset=100

returns the same results. Can paging be used on includes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can paginate in MusicBrainz but you cannot page through a bucket request.  In order to see all of the recordings, you need to query the web service for each track with:

http://musicbrainz.org/ws/2/recording?artist=MBID&offset=VALUE&limit=100

Hope this helps!
Michael

Comment: I think you mean: 
http://musicbrainz.tranquilbase.org/ws/2/recording?artist=72c536dc-7137-4477-a521-567eeb840fa8&offset=&limit=100